# How can I control the instrument “msgbox” in VB. net

Tags: vb.net-2010, messagebox

Can I show custom buttons inside MsgBox? I want different buttons from the regular buttons for msgbox which are:

1. OK
2. Cancel
3. Abort
4. Retry
5. Ignore
6. Yes
7. No

How can I control the text and value of these buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MsgBox is tied directly to the underlying Windows UI and cannot be easily changed or extended.
You should create your own class or look for an already made project like this one

[A versatile MessageBox replacement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/454307/A-versatile-MessageBox-replacement)

Well, a bit of research on the subject has lead me to this old article and code

[Using Windows Hooks to Enhance MessageBox in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188920.aspx)

but it is a lot of work and perhaps you could better use your time to build your own message class.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the message box but there would be limitations. The maximum number of buttons would be 3. The text of the buttons can be changed.

Add the following class to your project which will help you change the text of the buttons.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class MessageClass

Private Shared mLabels() As String    '' Desired new labels
Private Shared mLabelIndex As Integer '' Next caption to update

Public Shared Sub PatchMsgBox(ByVal labels() As String)
    ''--- Updates message box buttons
    mLabels = labels
    Application.OpenForms(0).BeginInvoke(New FindWindowDelegate(AddressOf FindMsgBox), GetCurrentThreadId())
End Sub

Private Shared Sub FindMsgBox(ByVal tid As Integer)
    ''--- Enumerate the windows owned by the UI thread
    EnumThreadWindows(tid, AddressOf EnumWindow, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub

Private Shared Function EnumWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean
    ''--- Is this the message box?
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(256)
    GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity)
    If sb.ToString() <> "#32770" Then Return True
    ''--- Got it, now find the buttons
    mLabelIndex = 0
    EnumChildWindows(hWnd, AddressOf FindButtons, IntPtr.Zero)
    Return False
End Function

Private Shared Function FindButtons(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(256)
    GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity)
    If sb.ToString() = "Button" And mLabelIndex <= UBound(mLabels) Then
        ''--- Got one, update text
        SetWindowText(hWnd, mLabels(mLabelIndex))
        mLabelIndex += 1
    End If
    Return True
End Function

''--- P/Invoke declarations
Private Delegate Sub FindWindowDelegate(ByVal tid As Integer)
Private Delegate Function EnumWindowDelegate(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function EnumThreadWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal tid As Integer, ByVal callback As EnumWindowDelegate, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal callback As EnumWindowDelegate, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function GetClassName Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal name As StringBuilder, ByVal maxlen As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Auto Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Integer
Private Declare Auto Function SetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal text As String) As Boolean

End Class
```

Now use the class in the following way to show the messages:

```
MessageClass.PatchMsgBox(New String() {"Button name 1", "Button name 2"})
Dim Result As DialogResult = MsgBox("Message", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Title")
```

Now you need to handle your Result from the message box which would be based on the message box style you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a way to do this, and it's work fine for me.

I created a new form, and i make it look like a "msgbox" and i add to it what i need like buttons, Pictures... and anything else, but when i need to show the form (msgbox)... i use this code :

```
Form1.showDialog()
```

instead of write : `Form1.Show()`

You can make it look exactly like a "msgbox" with a custom buttons, and you can't do anything in the other opened windows to close this form (exactly like a "msgbox").

I don't know... i just found this way... very good and easy.